# Can there be more than one init.pp?

Tags: linux, unix, manifest, puppet, puppet-enterprise

How many different init.pp can be there?
Let's say if I have 10 different manifests that will do different jobs across the servers, should I define all the classes in one init.pp?

If the answer is yes, won't it get confusing once too many information are inside the single init.pp?

Answer (score 3):

No, you can add different modules in different directories and have separate `init.pp`'s there.

Examples:

`apache2/manifests/init.pp`:

```
class apache2  {
   do some stuff;
}
```

`postfix/manifests/init.pp`:

```
class postfix {
   do other stuff;
}
```

`my_mail_and_web_server/manifests/init.pp`:

```
class my_mail_and_web_server {
    class { 'apache2':; }
    class { 'postfix':; }
}
```

`manifests/site.pp`:

```
node 'mailandweb.mycompany.com' {
    class { 'my_mail_and_web_server':; }
}
```

See https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/modules_fundamentals.html for more details on how to structure your modules.